# Trigger no se ejecuta

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, trigger

Estoy utilizando el framework express para aprender a crear una res api sencilla con node y mysql y tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
router.post('/CrearUsuario',function(req,res,next){
    postData = Array()
    postData.push(req.body.primerNombre);
    postData.push(req.body.segundoNombre);
    postData.push(req.body.primerApellido);
    postData.push(req.body.segundoApellido);
    postData.push(req.body.usuario);
    postData.push(req.body.contrasena);
    postData.push(req.body.administrador);
    console.log(postData);
    conection.query('insert into usuarios (primerNombre,segundoNombre,primerApellido,segundoApellido,usuario,contrasena,administrador) values (?)',[postData] ,function(error,result,fields){
    if(error) throw error
        res.json({ code : 200 , data : "Usuario ha sido agregado con exito"});
    })
})
```

le envio el siguiente json desde el sofware insomnia a esa dirección:

```
{
"primerNombre":"Marcia",
"segundoNombre":"Cristina",
"primerApellido":"Aguilera",
"segundoApellido":null,
"usuario":"marciAguilera",
"contrasena":"marcia1234",
"administrador":false
}
```

el la base de datos tengo el siguiente trigger:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER encodePass BEFORE INSERT ON usuarios
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SET NEW.contrasena = AES_ENCRYPT(NEW.contrasena,@pass);
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

Ahora bien si yo hiciera un insert desde la consola de la base de datos este trigger ecripta la contraseña, pero si lo hago desde la api que ejecuta un insert en la base de datos la contraseña me aparece como null.

Ejemplo de inserciones de datos en la bd los que tienen la contraseña encriptada fueron ingresados directamente desde la consola y los que tienen null fueron ingresados desde la api ¿porque pasa esto?

[image: Ejemplo de inserciones de datos en la bd los que tienen la contraseña encriptada fueron ingresados directamente desde la consola y los que tienen null fueron ingresados desde la api ¿porque pasa esto?]

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo para que encripte cuando se ingresan datos desde la api?

Comment: Qué usuario utilizas para hacer el insert por consola? Y cuando lo haces via api, qué usuario utiliza?

Comment: ¿Cómo se asigna el valor de la variable definida por usuario `@pass` en consola y en el API?, en el caso del API parece que `@pass` es `NULL`.

Comment: Gracias wchiquito me fue de mucha ayuda tu comentario y esq no habia tomado en cuenta que @pass era una variable de session y que en la session que habre node para ejecutar el query no existia o es null por eso el resultado inesperadoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que en la session que se habre con node la variable @pass no existia por lo tanto la funcion de encriptar fallaba retornando un null, la solucion es crear @pass en el trigger

Comment: Recuerde que existe diferencia entre una variable definida por el usuario (en su caso `@pass`) y una variable local (`pass`), ver [9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) y [13.6.4 Variables in Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-variables.html) (ambos enlaces en inglés). Con la información que indica, una variable local, posiblemente, sería una mejor opción.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la info @wichiquito por la información